# How to cause a job to finish with warning in Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, exit-code

I mean to get this status:

[image]

I can finish my job with failure, by "exit 1" , but can't do the same with warning

Answer (score 24):

This is possible since [13.8](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#allow_failureexit_codes):

```
test_job:
  script:
    - execute_script_that_will_fail 
  # if the script exit code is 137 or 255 the job will allow to be 
  # failed and the pipeline will continue to run
  allow_failure:
    exit_codes: # User defined exit code
      - 137
      - 255
```

Comment: Thank you. Will this also automatically mark the job as "failed with warnings" or will it appear like any other passed job?

Answer (score 22):

Warnings in Gitlab aren't an exit status you can control from within the job, but a configuration option for the job itself. In the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file, you need to add the flag [`allow_failure`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#allow_failure):

```
somejob:
  stage: test
  script:
    - some_script
  allow_failure: true
```

If this job then fails (i.e., terminates with an exit code that isn't `0`), it will end with a warning status and not block the pipeline from continuing.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works.Another question related to this: Is there any way to pass the status dynamically to "allow_failure"? I mean to keep some boolean variable and to change it from within the job.

Comment: @Zhenya1980 I can't think of any way to this offhand, sorry

Comment: You can upvote this so that it becomes possible: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/16733

Comment: you could also do:
script:
    - some_script || true
    - script part 2 that looks at variables or whatever happened as part of script 1 and fails if necessary.
you would remove the allow_failure: true chunk.

Ugh, since formatting isn't allowed in comments.
basically by adding the || true to the end of every script in the script section you can ensure none of it will fail and then look at conditions as the last step in the script process and decide to fail.